# NOE Model and Hammerstein-Wiener Model Similarities in System Identification

Tags: modeling, simulation, nonlinearity

A nonlinear OE Model is defined as such:

> \begin{align}
> \hat{y} &= g(\phi(t))  \\
> \phi(t) &= (u(t), u(t-1), ..., u(t-n_u), \hat{y}(t-1), ..., \hat{y}(t-n_y))^T
> \end{align}

where $g$ can be any nonlinear function.

Is this model equivalent to a Hammerstein-Wiender model where there is no input nonlinearity (Wiener model)?

[image: Hammerstein-Wiender Model]

where the $B$ polynomial corresponds to the input $u$ and $F$ polynomial corresponds to the model output $\hat{y}$.